# F# Ignore a pattern in pattern match

Tags: functional-programming, f#, pattern-matching

I may be thinking about this the wrong way but I want to ignore any case other than the `Some` case. Here is some sample code that I'm using `| _ -> ignore` but that seems wrong. Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this? I'm converting some OOP C# code to F# and might be coming at it wrong.

```
match solarSystem.MinerCoords |> Map.tryFind minerId with
| Some currentMinerCoords ->
    match solarSystem.Minables |> Map.tryFind currentMinerCoords with
    | Some _ ->
        do! GetMinerActor(minerId).StopMining() |> Async.AwaitTask
    | _ -> ignore
| _ -> ignore
```

Comment: `ignore` needs an argument. You're returning the whole function here. You should use a single `()` instead, or `return()` in the CE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make every branch producing an async, then you can execute it after all. Like this:

```
let dummyAsync = async { return () }
let theAsync =
    match solarSystem.MinerCoords |> Map.tryFind minerId with
    | Some currentMinerCoords when solarSystem.Minables |> Map.tryFind currentMinerCoords |> Option.isSome ->
        GetMinerActor(minerId).StopMining() |> Async.AwaitTask
    | _ ->
        dummyAsync
do! theAsync
```

Notice the use of `when` keyword to remove one unnecessary branch.

More idiomatically, when you are matching multiple option values in a nested manner, then you should use the functions `Option.bind` and/or `Option.map`:

```
let dummyAsync = async { return () }
let theAsync =
    solarSystem.MinerCoords
    |> Map.tryFind minerId
    |> Option.bind (fun currentMinerCoords -> solarSystem.Minables |> Map.tryFind currentMinerCoords)
    |> Option.map (fun _ -> GetMinerActor(minerId).StopMining() |> Async.AwaitTask)
    |> Option.defaultValue dummyAsync
do! theAsync
```

Comment: I'm trying to adopt the more idiomatic approach but I'm getting this error: `The type 'Async<'a>' does not match the type 'Async<unit> list'`

 with this code:

```
  let dummyAsync = [(async { return () })]
                        do! solarSystem.MinersAtCoords 
                            |> Map.tryFind coords
                            |> Option.map (fun miners -> miners |> List.map (fun id -> GetMinerActor(id).StartMining(minableId) |> Async.AwaitTask))
                            |> Option.defaultValue dummyAsync
```

The types look like they should match up though

Comment: dummyAsync is not a list, please remove [ and ]

Comment: I thought that the preceding `Option.map (fun /*some code */ |> Async.AwaitTask))` made it so that I need to make dummyAsync a list since it's returning a list of asyncs?

*edit* this is for a different piece of code (not the one you answered the original question for

Comment: No, Option.map does not return a list, it returns an option value of the value returned inside the passed function.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're inside an `async` computation expression that returns `Async<unit>`. So you should replace `ignore` with `return ()` (where `()` is the unit value) so that all branches return the same type:

```
match solarSystem.MinerCoords |> Map.tryFind minerId with
| Some currentMinerCoords ->
    match solarSystem.Minables |> Map.tryFind currentMinerCoords with
    | Some _ ->
        do! GetMinerActor(minerId).StopMining() |> Async.AwaitTask
    | _ -> return ()
| _ -> return ()
```

---

EDIT: A simplified version showing the whole async block, and how to continue running more code afterwards:

```
async {
    match Some 1 with
    | Some a ->
        printfn "Maybe do this"
        do! Async.Sleep 500
    | _ -> ()

    printfn "Always do this"
    do! Async.Sleep 500
    printfn "Finished" }
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. You're correct I'm in an async block. What if I don't want to return or end the function at that point? I want to keep going onto the next part of the function

Comment: @LukeP For `Async<unit>` you don't actually need to return unit, you can just write `()`. But whichever one you use, you can just write more code underneath. See my edited answer